# I am making a reminder app, and I have tried to use realm. I am using getInstance().This is the error I get

Tags: java, android, database, realm

Cannot convert io.realm.RealmConfiguration to android.content.Context.
**This is my activityclass**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder);

    rvListings = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.events);

    list = new ArrayList<ListingsModel>();

    // read the saved values in database


    Realm myRealm = Realm.getInstance(getBaseContext());
    results1 = myRealm.where(EventModelDB.class).findAll();

    for (int i = results1.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        EventModelDB c = results1.get(i);
        model = new ListingsModel();
        model.setEvent(c.getEvent());
        model.setTime(c.getTime());
        model.setDate(c.getDate());
        model.setTimestamp(c.getTimestamp());

        list.add(model);
    }


    adapter = new ListingsAdapter(list, getBaseContext());
    rvListings.setAdapter(adapter);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    //   mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    //  mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    rvListings.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
}
```

This is my ListingsAdapter.I get same error here. Here is the relevant part. I have even tried using this

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfig1 = new 
RealmConfiguration.Builder(getContext()).name("1testSave1.realm").build();
Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfig1);
Realm myRealm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig1);

    public class ListingsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListingsAdapter.Viewholder> {

    public ListingsAdapter(ArrayList<ListingsModel> data, Context context) {
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
}

    // long click an item to delete it from database
    holder.toplayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            // deleting the selected row from Realm database
            Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
            RealmResults<EventModelDB> result = realm.where(EventModelDB.class)
                    .equalTo("timestamp", data.get(position).getTimestamp())
                    .findAll();

            if(result != null){
                if(result.size() > 0){
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                    result.remove(0);
                    realm.commitTransaction();

                }
            }

        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: What version of Realm is this, 0.82.2?

Answer (score 1):

So assuming you remove the following from your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.2`
}
```

---

And replace it in your project level build gradle with the latest version

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.3.3"
```

And apply the plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// other plugins
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

---

Now we can talk about just how many things are wrong here, so first we should add

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.1.1'
}
```

Then we can do in Application class

```
public class CustomApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                                              .name("1testSave1.realm")
                                              .build());
    }
}
```

And then in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:name=".CustomApplication"
```

And then

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Realm realm;
    RealmResults<EventModelDB> results;
    RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<EventModelDB>> realmChangeListener = (results) -> {
        // actually, just keep this here
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder);

        rvListings = findViewById(R.id.events);

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        results = realm.where(EventModelDB.class).findAllAsync();
        results.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
        adapter = new ListingsAdapter(realm, results);
        rvListings.setAdapter(adapter);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        rvListings.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        results.removeAllChangeListeners();
        realm.close();
        results = null;
        realm = null;
    }
}
```

And

```
public class ListingsAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<EventModelDB, ListingsAdapter.Viewholder> {
    private final Realm realm;

    public ListingsAdapter(Realm realm, RealmResults<EventModelDB> results) {
        super(results, true);
        this.realm = realm;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Viewholder holder, int position) {
        EventModelDB event = getData().get(position);
        final long timestamp = event.getTimestamp();

        // long click an item to delete it from database
        holder.toplayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {        
                // deleting the selected row from Realm database
                realm.executeTransactionAsync((r) -> {
                    r.where(EventModelDB.class)
                        .equalTo("timestamp", timestamp)
                        .findAll()
                        .deleteAllFromRealm();
                });
            }
        });    
    }
}
```

Boom, fixed your boat

Answer (score 0):

After `setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder);`

Add this : `Realm.init(this);`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the Android context to Realm

```
Realm myRealm = Realm.getInstance(getBaseContext());
```

This needs to be a RealmConfiguration.

```
RealmConfiguration myConfig = new RealmConfiguration();
// config myConfig
Realm myRealm = Realm.getInstance(myConfig);
```

For more information see https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/#realms